# Replicating UIView drawRect in OpenGL ES

Tags: ios, opengl-es, uiview, drawrect

My iOS application draws into a bitmap (same size as my view) using Core Graphics. I want to push updated regions of the bitmap to the screen. (I've used the standard UIView drawRect method but I have some good reasons to switch to OpenGL).

I just want to replicate the same behavior as UIView/CALayer drawRect but in an OpenGL view. Essentially I would like to update dirty rectangles on my OpenGL view. Nothing more.

So far I've been able to create an OpenGL ES 1.1 view and push my entire bitmap on screen using a single quad (texture on a vertex array) for each update of my bitmap. Of course, this is pretty inefficient since I only need to refresh the dirty rectangle, not the whole view.

What would be the most efficient way to do that in OpenGL ES? Should I use a lattice of quads and update the texture of the quads that intersect with my dirty rectangle? (If I were to use that method, should I use VBO?) Is there a better way to do that?

FYI (just in case), I won't need rotation but will need to scale the entire OpenGL view.

UPDATE:
This method indeed works. However, there's a bug in iOS5.x on retina display devices that produces an artifact when using single buffering. The problem has been fixed in iOS6. I don't yet have a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply just update a part of the texture using TexSubImage, and redraw your standard full-screen quad, but with the scissor rect beeing set (glScissor) to the "dirty" part. The GL will then not draw any fragments outside this rect.

For this to work, you must of course use single buffering.

Comment: Thanks that works. To use single buffering:((CAEAGLLayer*)[self layer]).drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE],
                                        kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking,
                                        kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8,
                                        kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat,
                                        nil];

Comment: Would there be any advantage in using CVOpenGLESTextureCache?